# How to check from javascript that flash object is in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, flash, fullscreen

I need to check from javascript that given flash object is in fullscreen mode. I know that there is `stage.displayState` property but how to access it using `GetVariable`? Or maybe there is another way?

Thanks.

P.S. If your know how to do that from any other language it is ok too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll probably need to add a function inside AS that you can call from the JS layer:

```
// In your AS code
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

// Register a function you can call from JS
ExternalInterface.addCallback("isFullScreen", _isFullScreen);

// Returns true if fullscreen
private function _isFullScreen() :Boolean {
    return stage.displayState === StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN:
};
```

then, you should be able to call it from JS:

```
// Get a reference to the object element, change
// 'flashcontent' to the ID of your .swf in the DOM
var o = document.getElementById('flashcontent'),
    // Figure out it the player is in fullscreen mode
    isFullScreen = o.isFullScreen();
// Do something with isFullScreen value
```

docs for ExternalInterface [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), stage display state [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageDisplayState.html).

hope that helps. cheers!

Comment: and don't forget to set `allowScriptAccess` to true in your html wrapper

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my flash object so I cannot modify it. Can I get stage.displayState with ExternalInterface not altering AS code?

Comment: @DennisJaamann good catch! :) Sergius i don't believe there is a way to read back this property without being able to alter the AS code.